# Filter list of tuples

Tags: python, list, group-by, tuples

I have list:

```
print (L)
[('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), 
 ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('qux', 'one'), 
 ('qux', 'two'), ('oof', 'two'), ('oof', 'one'), ('oof', 'three')]
```

I want grouping by first element in tuples and  filter all tuples which contains `one` and `two` as second element.

So need filter out `('oof', 'two')` and `('foo', 'one')` because only one element for `foo` and 3 elements for `oof`.

Expected output - for each first element `bar`, `baz` second is `one` and `two` and length is 2:

```
print(L1)   
[('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), 
 ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), 
 ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')]
```

I try:

```
L = [b in ['one','two'] for a,b in L]
print (L)
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

What is nice/pythonic solution for it?

Comment: I personally think, that this is already elegant for the given situation.

Comment: `[item for item in L if item[1] in ["one", "two"]]`

Comment: What do you mean by grouping? Are the items already sorted?

Comment: I think yes, there are sorted by first element.

Comment: `sorted` does this automatically; it'll sort by the first item in the tuples, then the second and so on. `from pprint import pprint;pprint(sorted(L))` -- You can combine that with the builtin `filter` and a separate filter function and it may look better than a comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools, operator

# group the tuples by the first element
result = itertools.groupby(sorted(L), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
# convert the groups to lists
result = [list(group) for _, group in result]
# filter out those lists that don't contain exactly "one" and "two"
result = [group for group in result if set(y for x, y in group) == {'one', 'two'}]
# flatten the nested list into a list of tuples
result = [x for group in result for x in group]

print(result)
```

---

Note that this doesn't care about duplicate tuples:

```
L = [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('bar', 'two')]
# result = [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('bar', 'two')]
```

If you don't want these in your output, you can rewrite the filter condition (the 2nd list comprehension) like so:

```
result = [group for group in result if
             set(y for x, y in group) == {'one', 'two'} and len(group) == 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have done this via pandas groupby i.e

```
L = [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), 
 ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('qux', 'one'), 
 ('qux', 'two'), ('oof', 'two'), ('oof', 'one'), ('oof', 'three'),
 ('new','five'),('new','six')]

df  = pd.DataFrame(L)

s = df.groupby(0).size()
temp = s[s==2].index

idx = df[df[0].isin(temp)].groupby(0)[1].apply(lambda x : all(x.isin(['one','two'])))

df[df[0].isin(idx[idx].index)].apply(tuple,1).tolist()

[('bar', 'one'),
 ('bar', 'two'),
 ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'),
 ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two')]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this in one line ?

```
data=[('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two'), ('oof', 'two'), ('oof', 'two')]

from itertools import groupby

print(list(filter(lambda x:len(x)==2 and sorted((x[1][1],x[0][1]))==['one','two'],[list(b) for a,b in groupby(data,key=lambda x:x[0])])))
```

output:

```
[[('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two')], [('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two')], [('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')]]
```

detailed :

```
data=[('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two'), ('oof', 'two'), ('oof', 'one'), ('oof', 'three')]

dublicates={}

for i in data:
    if i[0] not in dublicates:
        dublicates[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        dublicates[i[0]].append(i[1])
print(dublicates)


final=[]
for j,i in dublicates.items():
    if len(i)==2:
        if 'one' and 'two' in i:
            final.extend([(j,'one'),(j, 'two')])

print(final)
```

output:

```
[('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two'), ('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two')]
```

Comment: You are really close, maybe need flattening add to the end of your solution?

Comment: @jezrael check now.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted solution. If you want, you can also upvote my question ;) Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael check one line solution and yeah i have upvoted your question :)

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `sorted` does this automatically. When sorting a list of tuples, it will sort by the first item, then the second and so on.

```
from pprint import pprint
def is_interesting(element):
    a, b = element
    return b in ('one', 'two')

result = sorted(filter(is_interesting, some_list))
pprint(result)
```

The output would be

```
[('bar', 'one'),
 ('bar', 'two'),
 ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'),
 ('foo', 'one'),
 ('oof', 'two'),
 ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two')]
```

Comment: So sorry I was not so unclear, I need also filter out `('oof', 'two'), ('oof', 'one'), ('oof', 'three')` because 3 elements.

Comment: I need exactly 2 elements and this elemenst are `one` and `two`. Maybe filter by set is necessary I guess.